# Convert odt to pdf in Java without starting soffice

Tags: java, pdf, openoffice.org

My problem seems quite basic but I haven't been able to find a neat solution.

I need to convert an `odt` file to a `pdf` file. [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) works nicely but `soffice` needs to be installed on the machine and started separately. For production constraints, I cannot assume `soffice` will be installed on the machines executing my app.

So is there a way to do this conversion simply by setting the right dependencies and calling the right piece of code? Can this be done simply using the [UNO API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html) or any other way? If yes, can you give me a little more insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If CUPS is available you may look into using CUPS-PDF. It is independent of soffice. It will simply "print" the .odt file to PDF format. [Here is the CUPS-PDF homepage](http://www.cups-pdf.de/).

Comment: Basically I need to be able to embed any dependency. Therefore I cannot assume cups-pdf is available.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [ODFDOM](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/ODFDOMConverterPDFViaIText).

Disclaimer: I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

JOD Converter works well, if dedicated server open office can be installed using headless option
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/194352/install-openoffice-for-headless-use

With Tomcat, you can run web app to convert any file supported by Open Office to PDF
  http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter